# $this - can't find the correct jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having real trouble finding which selectors to use to show some divs on my page as my html structure is overly complicated (wordpress comments system).

Instead of pasting it all here I've created a much simplified version of the layout and created a couple of fiddles.

1. This is the full page with all div's displayed :

https://jsfiddle.net/e25zvfyg/

2. This is how I want it to work. Basically the reply box and associated existing comments are hidden until "REPLY" is clicked and then the hidden divs slideDown. I've included my "non-working" JS in this fiddle. Hopefully somebody can show me where I'm going wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/yf3oagx7/

```
 (function ($) {
$('.single-f3ed-reply').hide();
$('.f3ed-reply').hide();
$('a.this-reply').click(function () {
    $('.single-f3ed-reply').hide();
    $(this).parents().next('.single-f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).parents().next('.f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parents()` returns *all* the elements that are above the selected element.  You don't want this, you want to go up only as far as a containing div/wrapper.

`.next()` returns the next item (filtered), which makes no sense in the context of `parents()`

Go up to the nearest wrapping div (`closest`), then down again (`find`) to the item you want:

```
    $(this).closest(".stream-wrap").find('.single-f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).closest(".stream-wrap").find('.f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yf3oagx7/1/

Comment: Absolute legend! Yes I know I had it wrong, been trying so many different things but I'm still pretty green when it comes to jQuery. I had tried 'find' and 'closest' previously but didn't have them in the right order at all.  Thanks so much, your explanation helps a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack:
https://jsfiddle.net/e25zvfyg/2/

Using:

```
$(this).closest('article').find('.single-f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
$(this).closest('article').find('.f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this --

```
(function ($) {
$('.single-f3ed-reply').hide();
$('.f3ed-reply').hide();
$('a.this-reply').click(function () {
    $('.single-f3ed-reply').hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.single-f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

You can also achieve this using jquery closest() function as well..

```
(function ($) {
$('.single-f3ed-reply').hide();
$('.f3ed-reply').hide();
$('a.this-reply').click(function () {
    $('.single-f3ed-reply').hide();
    $(this).closest('.stream-wrap').find('.single-f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).closest('.stream-wrap').find('.f3ed-reply').slideDown('fast');
    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Using multiple `.parent().parent()` tends to rely too heavily on the structure of the html.  In this case it will work fine as the structure is unlikely to change, but generally this will break easily if someone decides to add another wrapper div for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes. That is why 2nd solution is the better one.